# Avoiding creating event handlers when using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Let's assume this component structure in React:

```
function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('')
  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const {value} = e.target
    setInputValue(value)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <SpecialInput {...{inputValue, handleInputChange}} />
    </div>
  )
}

function SpecialInput({inputValue, handleInputChange}) {
  return (
    <input 
      type="text" 
      value={inputValue}
      onChange={handleInputChange} />
  )
}
```

This conventional pattern of event handlers litters the code IMO when they only destructure the event object.

What could be some preferable alternatives?

Comment: What is the reason here for not inlining the hook in the `SpecialInput` component?

Comment: It's a simulation of an app structure.

Answer (score 0):

Extracting value from event target that way is quite common as you have stated.

Where this is a recurring pattern in your application, you can have the operation extracted to a function. For example,

```js
function onValueChange(next) {
  return (event) => {
    next(event.target.value);
  }
}
```

Then used to decorate value change handlers.

```
<SpecialInput 
  handleInputChange={onValueChange(handleInputChange)}
  inputValue={inputValue}
/>
```